# How do I access Chromium extension API from Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to make a chromium extension that would expose an API to python selenium webdriver code? For example, I can make an extension with a background script, that would count the tabs with `chrome.tabs.query`, now I'd like to access that information from my python code using selenium webdriver.

I've been able to do this by querying background script from content script using `chrome.extension.sendMessage`, saving the data to `window.localStorage`, and fetching it to python with `Command.GET_LOCAL_STORAGE_ITEM` (or `execute_script`, doesn't matter), but is there a simpler way?